# Deleting multiple filenames from files in a text file with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to delete every line that contains the basename from all files listed in a folder.

I have 2 000 000 files in a folder but there should be 2 500 000 files. I have a missing.txt file that contains all the 2.5M filenames line by line. I want to delete all lines that I already have to restart my process and finish the 500 000 missing files.

My very simple script is :

```
for FILE in ../pdb/*; do
BNAME="$(basename ${FILE} _mini.pdb)"
sed "/${BNAME}/d" ./missing.txt
done
```

The problem is that sed doesn't delete the $BNAME lines in the missing.txt file. What am I doing wrong with sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a different approach:

**First** create a sorted list of the current files: `ls | sort > new_list.txt`. It should contain ~2ml rows.

**Then** sort the list of 2.5ml files `sort missing.txt > old_list.txt`

**Finally** extract the difference: `comm -23 old_list new_list`

It's much more efficient than 2ML instances of sed.

Comment: Or just use `awk` or similar to "diff" the two files.

Comment: The missing.txt doesn't contain extensions files. I've tried a for FILE in ../pdb/* ; do BNAME=`basename $FILE .pdb` ; echo $BNAME >> missing.txt but it takes forever. Should I try to add the .pdb extension with sed for every lines before I can try you approach?

Comment: @Grego Yes, I think you should.

Comment: "sed 's/$/.pdb/' old_list.txt > old_list2.txt" did the job in few seconds. I will try to sort and comm now.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. comm -23 old_list.txt new_list.txt > missed.txt. wc -l missed.txt -> 483167 !

Comment: And then "sed 's/.pdb$//' missed.txt > missed-final.txt" to remove the .pdb extention at the end of every line.